# How do I isort using ruff?

Tags: python, isort, ruff

I often work in very small projects which do not have config file. How do I use `ruff` in place of `isort` to sort the imports? I know that the following command is roughly equivalent to `black`:

```bash
ruff format .
```

The format command do not sort the imports. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/formatter/#sorting-imports):

> Currently, the Ruff formatter does not sort imports. In order to both sort imports and format, call the Ruff linter and then the formatter:

```
ruff check --select I --fix .
ruff format .
```